# List View Controls Greyed Out

Tags: lightning

In my sandbox, I want to edit an existing List View.  When I try to edit it, the controls are greyed out.  I have switched to different admin users and the controls are still greyed out.

How can I edit my list views?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to edit the recently viewed layout which is a special type of list view([search layout](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_recent_records_list_lex.htm&type=5)).
You can edit the recently viewed layout of an object by following these steps:

1. From Setup, at the top of the page, select Object Manager.
2. Click the label name of the object for the Recently Viewed list you want to modify.
3. From the menu of links at the top of the page, click Search
   Layouts.
4. In the far right of the Search Results row, click
   icon_list_item_dropdown_action and select Edit. Recently viewed lists use the Search Results search layout in Lightning. In Classic,
   recently viewed lists use the Tab search layout.
5. To add columns to
   the Recently Viewed list, select one or more fields from Available
   Fields and click Add. To remove columns, select one or more fields from Selected Fields and click Remove.
6. Order columns by selecting one or more fields from Selected Fields and clicking Up or Down.
7. Click Save.

For any list view layout which you create can be edited from this interface.
Read more from [here](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/lex_customization/lex_customization_list)

Comment: Thanks.  I have done the following: Setup->Object Manager->Contact>Search Layouts>Edit Default Layout Profile (all profiles using Def. Layout).  In the profile, I added 4 cols.  When I go back to Contact page and look at "Recently Viewed Contacts" List, I don't see the columns I have added.  When I look at "Recently Viewed", I see the columns that I have added.  What am I missing?  For Search Layout for SF Classic, there a List View Layout with 2 columns: COLUMNS DISPLAYED - N/A and BUTTONS DISPLAYED - with 4 items. When I edit this layout, there is no column names to select.

Answer (score 0):

In salesforce for sObjects you have two recently viewed list views, for example if you take a case(Object) it will have two list views named Recently Viewed & Recently Viewed Cases. The Search Layout changes you made will reflect on Recently Viewed. We cannot modify the Recently Viewed Cases List View.

When you want to display a list view on a Home Page, you can only place recently viewed cases out of two. Recently Viewed list view is not available for Home Page.

Thank You.